display all dates on x axis using seaborn objects
I am generating a stacked area plot using the seaborn objects class as from my understanding, seaborn barplot does not have stacking capabilities. The objects class is quite versatile but I have run into an issue with how the axis are presented. It only displays 3 dates and all efforts to display all the dates have been difficult.
data sample
t = ["2019-05-10 03:00:00", "2019-05-10 09:00:00", "2019-05-10 15:00:00", 
     "2019-05-10 21:00:00", "2019-05-11 03:00:00", "2019-05-11 09:00:00",
     "2019-05-11 15:00:00", "2019-05-11 21:00:00", "2019-05-12 03:00:00", 
     "2019-05-12 09:00:00", "2019-05-12 15:00:00", "2019-05-12 21:00:00",
     "2019-05-13 03:00:00", "2019-05-13 09:00:00", "2019-05-13 15:00:00", 
     "2019-05-13 21:00:00", "2019-05-14 03:00:00", "2019-05-14 09:00:00",
     "2019-05-14 15:00:00", "2019-05-14 21:00:00", "2019-05-15 03:00:00", 
     "2019-05-15 15:00:00", "2019-05-16 15:00:00",
     "2019-05-10 03:00:00", "2019-05-10 09:00:00", "2019-05-10 15:00:00", 
     "2019-05-10 21:00:00", "2019-05-11 03:00:00", "2019-05-11 09:00:00",
     "2019-05-11 15:00:00", "2019-05-11 21:00:00", "2019-05-12 03:00:00", 
     "2019-05-12 09:00:00", "2019-05-12 15:00:00", "2019-05-12 21:00:00",
     "2019-05-13 03:00:00", "2019-05-13 09:00:00", "2019-05-13 15:00:00", 
     "2019-05-13 21:00:00", "2019-05-14 03:00:00", "2019-05-14 09:00:00",
     "2019-05-14 15:00:00", "2019-05-14 21:00:00", "2019-05-15 03:00:00", 
     "2019-05-15 15:00:00", "2019-05-16 15:00:00"]

k = ["hit","hit","hit","hit","hit","hit","hit","hit","hit","hit","hit","hit",
     "hit","hit","hit","hit","hit","hit","hit","hit","hit","hit","hit",
     "mis","mis","mis","mis","mis","mis","mis","mis","mis","mis","mis","mis",
     "mis","mis","mis","mis","mis","mis","mis","mis","mis","mis","mis",]
v = [0.1, 0.7, 0.3, 0.4, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.4, 0.3, 0.4, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5,
     0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.4, 0.3, 0.4, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5,
     0.4, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.4, 0.3, 0.4, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3,
     0.4, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.4, 0.3, 0.4, 0.3]

mydf = pd.DataFrame({"date":t,"attack":k, "score":v})
mydf['date'] = mydf['date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))

Here is the code I used to build the graph
seaborn_objects.Plot(mydf, x="date", y="score",
                     color="attack").add(seaborn_objects.Area(), seaborn_objects.Stack())


I tried using matplotlib generate the axis in combination the seaborn objects scale but it ends up losing the temporal spacing and muddles the axis.
f, ax = pyplot.subplots()
data_plot = seaborn_objects.Plot(mydf, x="date", y="score",
                     color="attack").add(seaborn_objects.Area(), seaborn_objects.Stack()).scale(x=seaborn_objects.Nominal())
pyplot.xticks(rotation=90)  
data_plot.on(ax).show()



I do not know if this is the correct solution but this did what I wanted in regards to the problem at hand.
by adding the scale function with the seaborn object Temporal, I was able to expand the number of ticks to whatever I wanted.
code:
(
 seaborn_objects.Plot(mydf, x="date", y="score", color="attack")
    .add(seaborn_objects.Area(), seaborn_objects.Stack())
    .scale(x=seaborn_objects.Temporal().tick(upto=100))
)

